# Rails ActionMailer User Mailer No Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I'm not geting my user_mailer work. It says there's no method and I coudn't find out why:

From Rails:

```
NoMethodError in AtendimentosController#create
undefined method `welcome_email' for UserMailer:Module
```

From Rails C (manual test):

```
irb(main):027:0> ActionMailer::usermailer.send_welcome_email(from: "test@example.co", to: '...@gmail.com', subject: 'subjecto de teste', body: "Test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):27
        1: from (irb):27:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `usermailer' for ActionMailer:Module)
```

class UserMailer is located at /mailers/user_mailer/user_mailer.rb :

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_email(user)
    mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Welcome!")
  end
end
```

I'm calling at a controller:

```
  def send_mail
    UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver_later
  end
```

Comment: Where are you calling `send_mail`? Why are you passing `self` (the controller) to the mailer class? I suspect you want to send the user object through. Also, `@user` doesn't exist in the `welcome_email` method as you've posted it. You either need to instantiate it as `@user = user` if you're using it in your view, or just use `user.email` as the `:to =>` parameter.

Comment: Hello @scilence, thanks for the feedback. I've already tried to change and included a manual transaction with Rails C like you said, but still not working because of the "No method". The code example I took from the link below, but as I said, I already tried to change and even do a manual ActiveEmail job. https://altalogy.com/blog/rails-6-user-accounts-with-3-types-of-roles/

Answer (score 0):

You should move this class to `/mailers/user_mailer.rb`. When you put the file in a separate folder, it is required that the file begins with the `Module ModuleName`. So in your example, when you put this file in `/mailers/user_mailer/user_mailer.rb` it should look like this:

```
module UserMailer
  class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def welcome_email(user)
      mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "Welcome!")
    end
  end
end
```

And then you call it: `UserMailer::UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver`